# Making a brute force tool on java: How to make computer automatically input username and password on a website

Tags: java, passwords, autologin

I've been trying to make a brute-force machine (just for a challenge), where the user would basically input login website URL, username box inspect element, password box inspect element, a target username, and a file that lists many possible passwords for the machine to brute force with. This is a text-based program that can be run on console/command prompt, to keep it simple.

After quite a lot of research, I still wasn't able to find a way to get the computer to automatically input the passwords into the password element the user has provided, on the web. I've been inspired to make this program on java after seeing it done on python, you can see the code here:
https://gist.github.com/climbpg/73e2204bceb26464a8112f31c29ac67c, or the full project is here: https://github.com/metachar/Hatch

Is there any way that you code so that the computer inputs values itself on to the websites login boxes, and attempt to bruteforce?? Please share your thoughts/opinions/suggestions how I can do so

Answer (score 0):

i think we can use TestNG DataProvider and we can read data from excel files it makes bruteforce search